# Python optimization problem: classifier with restrictions

Tags: python, optimization, classification, divider, operations-research

Is there a function/package in python that as evenly as possible distributes a number of points over groups/teams, but with restrictions for every team (type of points, etc.)?

So for example you have red, blue and yellow points. And then 5 teams, but one team can have max 4 blue, and another team needs to have 2 points difference between yellow and blue, etcetera.

Comment: You might be able to pose this as an optimization problem, and there are packages for that. You could check out [PuLP](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/).

Answer (score 0):

For simple optimization problems, you could look into [PuLP](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp) like already mentioned.

If you are facing more difficult optimization problems with lots of constraints and where performance is also a concern, you might want to look into [MiniZinc](https://minizinc-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [OR-Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/) which are some of the best open source solutions available for Python.